# Make a build in dojo 1.7.2

Tags: dojo

Well, I read all about build and all about dojo. Three days nightmare and so on...  Need some help.

I'm using the last version of dojo. 1.7.2 in:

```
</sites/somesite/scripts/dojo17>
which contains 
--dojo
--dijit
--dojox
--utils
```

I use the following profile:

```
dependencies = {
stripConsole: "all",
action: "release",
optimize: "shrinksafe",
layerOptimize: "shrinksafe",
//optimize: "closure",
//layerOptimize: "closure",
//mini: true,
//localeList : 'en-us', 
//cssOptimize: "comments",      
//selectorEngine: "acme",
releaseName: "content7",
layers: [
{
    // This is a specially named layer, literally 'dojo.js'
    // adding dependencies to this layer will include the modules
    // in addition to the standard dojo.js base APIs.
    name: "dojo.js",
    customBase : true,
        dependencies: [ 
          "dojo.fx",
          "dijit.form.Button",              
          "dojox.gauges.AnalogGauge",
          "dojox.gauges.AnalogArcIndicator",
          "dojox.gauges.AnalogNeedleIndicator",
          "myApp.smartmix"
    ]           
    }
],
prefixes: [
    [ "dijit", "../dijit" ], 
    [ "dojox", "../dojox" ],
    [ "myApp", "../../../myApp" ]
]
};
```

**then i use this build script**

```
./build.sh profile=../../../../myApp/myApp.profile.js releaseDir=../../../release
```

And I got the

```
</sites/somesite/scripts/release/content7>
which contains
--dijit
--dojo
--dojox
--myApp
```

NOW in my index.html file I have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var djConfig = {
        parseOnLoad: true,
        isDebug: false,
        modulePaths: {
            'myApp': '../myApp'
        }
    };
//]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/release/content7/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<script>
    dojo.require('myApp.smartmix');
</script>
```

And YES this reduce the 230 files loaded without the build to 153 files.
BUT stills I (want to) believe that is posibble to reduce to one or 2 files.

But HOW?????

Please, some help will be appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, your profile is not right.

**1st of all**: You are using `customBase`, which is an advanced property for creating a minimal version of dojo core.  I don't think you want that, do you?  Normally, you just let dojo build its core normally, and that ends up as dojo.js in your output dir.

**2nd of all**: Every `layer` entry there will generate a minified .js file with all the files in `dependencies` inside it.

So, if you want your `myApp` stuff in a built JS file, you'll need to create a layer, and put your files in its dependencies.

Dojo will still generate all the individual files - but you don't have to deploy them.  Just deploy the layer files.  I usually have a layer for Dojo core, a layer for the dijit/dojox stuff I want, and then a layer for my custom JS.  Then there are three JS files, which dojo will output in the dojo dir, and they are used in the HTML page.

Comment: **1st**: ok I remove the `customBase`, just for now because I really want a very little .js.
**2nd**: I need a minified .js with all the dependencies so my html wont't have to call all others .js (153 files!!!!). ***3rd*** The build still made 153 files. I just want one file with all the dependencies inside.

Comment: Dojo will still create all the individual files - but you don't have to deploy them.  You just deploy the files that are created for your layers.  I don't see in your profile where you have a layer that gathers together all *your* custom JS, and you need one.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
layers: [
{
// this is a layer 'application', which will cache all 
// dependencies to smartmix and declare smartmix in the same file
    name: "../../../myApp/smartmix.js",
        dependencies: [ 
          "dojo.fx",
          "dijit.form.Button",              
          "dojox.gauges.AnalogGauge",
          "dojox.gauges.AnalogArcIndicator",
          "dojox.gauges.AnalogNeedleIndicator",
          "myApp.smartmix"
    ]           
    }
],
...
```

you will need only two requests;

`<script src=..dojo.js></script>`

and

`<script>require(["myApp.smartmix"], function(smartmixApplication) { });</script>`